# How it's possible to take the best image resolution with A51 in React-Native with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing an application on React-Native with Expo on the Samsung A51.

I want to take a picture with the format "3:4" with 48MP and no the format "3:4" with 12MP.

When I'm using the method `getSupportedRatiosAsync()` I have this return :

```
Array [
  "1:1",
  "3:2",
  "4:3",
  "11:9",
  "16:9",
]
```

but the format "3:4" is with 12MP.

I want to know how can I choose the format with 48MP.

This is my configuration :

```
"expo": "^39.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
```

Thank you.